# Using autocomplete to save a foreign key reference or create a new entity if it's a new item

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I have three fields, called Country, Department and City.

[image]

There are three tables in my database that a user can type into. The jQuery autocomplete library lets the users type in names and have it fill out. I want to let my users select from existing countries/departments/cities but also let them create a brand new item if it's not there for them to choose.

```
Country     Department     City
----------  ----------     ---------
CountryId   DepartmentId   CityId
Name        Name           Name
            CountryId      DepartmentId
```

I'm having a hard time trying to figure this seemingly simple process.

Here's my code:

```
EFRegistryCountryRepository registryCountryRepository = new EFRegistryCountryRepository();
var country = registryCountryRepository.FindAllRegistryCountries().SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == model.Country);
if (country == null)
{
    RegistryCountry newCountry = new RegistryCountry();
    newCountry.Name = model.Country;
    registryCountryRepository.AddRegistryCountry(newCountry);
    registryCountryRepository.SaveChanges();
}

EFRegistryDepartmentRepository registryDepartmentRepository = new EFRegistryDepartmentRepository();
var department = registryDepartmentRepository.FindAllRegistryDepartments().SingleOrDefault(d => d.Name == model.Department && d.RegistryCountry.Name == model.Country);
if (department == null)
{
    RegistryDepartment newDepartment = new RegistryDepartment();
    newDepartment.RegistryCountryId = country.RegistryCountryId;
    newDepartment.Name = model.Department;
    registryDepartmentRepository.AddRegistryDepartment(newDepartment);
    registryDepartmentRepository.SaveChanges();
}

EFRegistryCityRepository registryCityRepository = new EFRegistryCityRepository();
var city = registryCityRepository.FindAllRegistryCities().SingleOrDefault(d => d.Name == model.City);
if (city == null)
{
    RegistryCity newCity = new RegistryCity();
    newCity.RegistryDepartmentId = department.RegistryDepartmentId;
    newCity.Name = model.City;
    registryCityRepository.AddRegistryCities(newCity);
    registryCityRepository.SaveChanges();
}
```

First off, there's the problem if the Country doesn't exist, I can't access that newly created Country from the Department bit of code since it's declared inside the `if (country == null)` condition.

I feel this is kind of convoluted and I'd appreciate any suggestion on how to **cleanly** code this requirement. I'm sure it's not as hard as my brain is telling me.

Comment: I figured it out, and I'll post my answer once I can.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I am looking at your question a bit simplistically, or didn’t understood your main idea, but you should be able to set the variable outside the if to the inner variable once you have saved the item, EntityFramework will populate your Id field with the Identity value from the DB,
so for instance for the country bit of your code could be:

```
var country = registryCountryRepository.FindAllRegistryCountries().SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == model.Country);
if (country == null) 
{ 
    RegistryCountry newCountry = new RegistryCountry(); 
    newCountry.Name = model.Country; 
    registryCountryRepository.AddRegistryCountry(newCountry); 
    registryCountryRepository.SaveChanges(); 
    **country = newCountry**
}
```

this would enable you to use the country object to check for the CountryId on the Department If, and you can use the same process inside the Department If to use on the City If